# Creating a local vector inside a function, then pass it as a reference to other functions which store it as a reference

Tags: c++

Is there any potential danger in this code?

```
void f(){
    std::vector<int> v;
    ...
    g(v);
}

void g(std::vector<int> &a){
    ... //store a by reference in variable blah (global)
}
```

v is destroyed when the call to f() is finished, but blah will still be referencing to v. Will blah become invalid? Is there a better way to do this while not making unnecessary copies of the vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the answer James provided, there is a third possibility, having the same readability as your first idea without the dangling reference, without heap allocation of the vector itself and without unnecessary copies:

```
std::vector<int> global; //somewehere - you don't have it really global, do you?

void f() {
  std::vector<int> vf; 
  /* ... */
  g(std::move(vf));
}

void g(std::vector<int> vg) //by value!
{
  /* ... */
  global.swap(vg);
}
```

Since you move `vf` "out of" `f()`, `vg`'s move-ctor is called, meaning it just takes ownership of the resources previously owned by `vf`, so no unnecessary copies and allocations are made. The `swap()` in `g()` only works if `global` exists before the call to `g()` (and thus `f()`). You said you want to store the vector in a reference, so I assume `g()` in fact *creates* the storage object and there is no `global` before the call. Then instead of swapping with an existing object `vg` should just be passed on via `std::move` to the storage object.

In total, you then really create only one vector (`vf`), all the others are really the same, `move`d on from the original, so you have basically the same performance as passing by reference, but without the dangling ref.

(For the nitpickers: Yes, moving a vector is a bit more than passing a ref, typically copying and zeroing three pointers instead of copying one. But it's really nothing compared to heap allocations, vector copies etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is the problem you describe. Either create `v` on the heap

```
void f()
{
    std::vector<int>* v = new std::vector<int>();
    // ...
    g(v);
}

void g(std::vector<int>* a)
{
    // Store in blah
    // But don't forget to delete it.
}
```

or have it as a global from the start.

```
std::vector<int> v;

void f()
{
    g();
}

void g()
{
    // Use v;
}
```